# Leetcode 20 Valid Brackets another solution

Tags: brackets

I am just so curious about this solution I saw on the website and cannot understand it.

The question is:
Given a string s containing just the characters '(', ')', '{', '}', '[' and ']', determine if the input string is valid. An input string is valid if:

Open brackets must be closed by the same type of brackets.
Open brackets must be closed in the correct order.

And here's the solution：

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isValid(String s) {
        int len = s.length() / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            s = s.replace("()", "").replace("{}", "").replace("[]", "");
        }

        return s.length() == 0;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why it still works if the input is something like "([{}])". Does the replace() method not scan by sequence? I'm so confused.

Comment: In each iteration of your loop you are removing up to one matching bracket (that has nothing in between it) of each type and you iterate `s.length()/2` times in total. Given your example you go `([{}])` -> `([])` -> `()` -> ``.

Comment: This might work, but has greater time complexity.